# Raspberry Pi Python Error

Tags: python

I tried to install distribute or setuptools which has to be done prior to installing pip on the Raspberry Pi.

The command used was `$ curl http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py | python`

However I got the following error. I can copy past the entire terminal script if requested.

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/test-easy-install-2082.pth'
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: have you tried doing it with sudo at the front, or installing from a package (sudo apt-get install python-setuptools)?

Comment: sudo apt-get worked!

Comment: why don't you write that up as an answer an accept it.

Comment: You should note that the curl line above downloads an unknown script from the Internet and then executes it sight unseen. You might trust python-distibute.org, but that's still a very bad thing to do :)

Answer (score 2):

Try putting

```
sudo
```

at the front.

Or try installing from a package like so:

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

(adding this answer here instead of in the comments)

Comment: `sudo curl ... | python` is still insufficient, it makes the root user fetch a URL and then run `python` as the local user. `curl ... | sudo python` does what you would expect, but note the warning made by XTL: directly running scripts from remote sources without any form of verification is highly insecure.